# Ajax , Jquery, calling procedure with $.ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a click event on Jquery, I am getting arrays with help of $.ajax and post, after that I am calling another procedure in a loop . Second procedure has a $.ajax too , is it allowed ? My script seems not working, I dont know what would wrong ?
Just give me any hint or clue please
And feel free to ask any questions

code :

```
$("#list").click(function(){                  
   var ptext ="";
   $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "phpname.php",
   data: ({
   newtask: "grab"
    }),
   dataType: "json",
   success: function(data){
   $.each(data, function(key, value) {
   ptext=value.name;    
   parseclick(ptext);   
   });
   }    
   });  
 });    
  });

function parseclick(ptext)
 {
    $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "phpname.php",
   data: ({
          grab_ads : "grab",
          list_url : ptext

          }),
   dataType: "html",
   success: function(msg){

     $("#all_name").append(msg);
     var part= msg.split("#url#");  
     $("#current_num").val(part[0]);
       }    
         });        
                                  });
```

}

Comment: hint: post code and try to put some effort in your questions; clue: it is allowed, but if it does what you expect we can't say.

Comment: You should "feel free to ask any questions", however please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) first.

Comment: ok let me add code , I just thought it is not allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's allowed. But if you make an Ajax call in your second precedure without the asynchronously option set to false, the loop will create a bunch of Ajax calls at the same time without waiting for a response from your server.

edit: After you added an example, I can see too many closed brackets.

Comment: yes you are are right, at the end I have more brackets, now it works. Thanks